# SharePoint Business Connectiviy Data Model Update method failing

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint

I have an external list in SharePoint that references a BCDM I created inside visual studio. The entity as an ID that is auto generated in the database, which means it's read-only.

Create and read method works fine, I'm trying to implement the update method. I have set an input parameter that match my entity and I'm getting this error.

*Failed to update a list item for this external list based on the Entity(External Content Type) ‘Notification’ in EntityNamespace ‘Namespace’. Details: The TypeDescriptor with name ‘Id’ in the Method ‘Microsoft.SharePoint.BusinessData.MetadataModel.Static.Method’ on Entity (External Content Type) with Name ‘Namespace’ in Namespace ‘Notification’ is marked ‘PreUpdaterField’, but is contained by another TypeDescriptor marked ‘PreUpdaterField’.*

I tried every possible combinaison to make this work, make the id type descriptor read only, pre-updater field = true/ false/, updater field = true/false, removing it, adding another parameter outside the entity. NOTHING WORKS !!! Obviously, I'm about to commit a murder as something so simple just turned out to be the biggest waste of time in my programmation history. What can I do to make this works??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved and is explained here:

http://www.dotnetmikael.com/2014/02/sharepoint-2013-bcdm-with-visual-studio.html